# Command that does absolutely nothing

Tags: functions, commands

Is there an Emacs command that does absolutely nothing ?

Comment: Specify what you mean by "absolutely nothing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, any function has to do *something*: it must return a value.  However, `ignore` does nothing more than that:

> `ignore` is an interactive native-compiled Lisp function in `subr.el`.
>
> It is bound to `M-<noname>`, `C-<noname>` and `C-M-<drag-mouse-1>`, and many
> ordinary text characters.
>
> `(ignore &rest ARGUMENTS)`
>
> Do nothing and return `nil`. This function accepts any number of
> `ARGUMENTS`, but ignores them.